# sed command does not work as expected in gitlab-ci-runner

Tags: awk, sed, replace, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a yaml file like below:

```
airflow:
    images:
       test1:
           fact1: value1
           fact2: value2
           fact3: value3
    dags:
        test2:
            fact4: value4
            fact5: value5
```

I want to update the value of fact3(value3) by running a command during gitlab CI. Note that this is a part of the required yaml file and also I don't know the exact value of the fact3 always. I want to update this value using sed and awk commands.
I have tried this:

```
# Set the path to the YAML file
yaml_file="test.yaml"

# Get the current value
current_value=$(awk '/^airflow:/,/^ *$/' $yaml_file | grep fact3 | awk '{print $2}')

# Update the value in the YAML file
sed -i "s/\(^\s*fact3\s*:\s*\)$current_value/\1$new_value/" $yaml_file
```

Note that here new_value is a gitlab variable. The issue is when I execute this command it does not replace the value. Instead of that it appends the new value with the old value.
For an example if my new value is "new" after updating it shows the fact3 as

```
fact3: newvalue3
```

But when I execute this in my local it works as expected. I couldn't figure out the issue on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is commonly available and has a YAML parser.

Given your example:

```
---
airflow:
    images:
       test1:
           fact1: value1
           fact2: value2
           fact3: value3
    dags:
        test2:
            fact4: value4
            fact5: value5
```

Here is a simple Ruby to change a YAML path value:

```
ruby -r yaml -e 'd=YAML.load($<.read)
d["airflow"]["images"]["test1"]["fact3"]="newvalue3"
puts d.to_yaml
' file.yaml
```

Prints:

```
---
airflow:
  images:
    test1:
      fact1: value1
      fact2: value2
      fact3: newvalue3
  dags:
    test2:
      fact4: value4
      fact5: value5
```